# Missing comma in SQL command and statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem from this trigger

```
create or replace trigger HAPUS_PENDUDUK 
after delete on system.PENDUDUK
for each row
BEGIN
  insert into penduduk_backup values (
     old_nip , old_nama, nama_user, tanggal_perubahan || old: nip, old: nama,
     current_user, sysdate()
  );
END;
```

After running it writes:

```
Error(5,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(5,94): PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
```

but I can't understand where I missed a comma and statment ignored.

Comment: Does your `pendudik_backup` table actually have four columns, and you're trying to insert using two values from the `pendudk` table plus the current date and user? You seem to be putting the column names into the values clause, and misusing the concatenation operator, as well as not understanding how `old` works. Are you really creating your own objects in the `system` schema? And can you show the DDL for both tables?

Answer (score 1):

You are not referring to `OLD`'s columns correctly:

```
create or replace trigger HAPUS_PENDUDUK 
after delete on system.PENDUDUK
for each row
BEGIN
  insert into penduduk_backup values (
     old_nip , old_nama, nama_user, tanggal_perubahan || :OLD.nip, OLD.nama,
     current_user, sysdate()
  );
END;
```